# Помогите подобрать XPath запрос

Tags: html, css, html5, парсер, xpath

Собираю небольшой парсер с помощью browser automation studio и столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно выделить 1:1 с помощью css или XPath - вот только я совсем запутался как это можно сделать.
Помогите пожалуйста

https://24score.pro/football/match/565728-burnley-everton

```
<td class="left">
                <span class="square bgloss">П</span>
                <b>2:1</b>
                (1:1)   
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//td[@class='left'][position()>1]/text()[3]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]